# Tabularx table with multirows and multicolumns

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, multicolumn

Bundled images link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew3tL.jpg

I want to achieve this formatting of cells(incuding automatic linebreaks working or alternatively a good way to manually do it):

What I want to end up with(made in MS Word) :

[image]

However halfway in I saw that linebreaks apparently do not work within multirow cells:

What happens with the linebreaks? https://i.stack.imgur.com/znu9V.jpg

[image]

Then I tried splitting the text up to the 2 different cells but couldn't find a way to move down the one cell down so the text looks as if it was inside one cell

What happens with split text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umTmX.jpg

[image]

Can you please provide me a working example for this table that includes automatic linebreaks? The last column really is relatively long.

I hacked something together but it isn't quite what I wanted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU0la.jpg

Corrections are written in red. The very right column works great but the others don't quite do what I want them to do.
Here is the code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{multirow, tabularx, ragged2e}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|C|C|C|C}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Text} & \multicolumn{2}{C|}{Text} & Very long text \\ \cline{2-4}
    & \multicolumn{2}{C|}{Text} & Very long text \\ \hline

    \multirow{1}{*}[-3.9em]{Text} & \multicolumn{2}{C|}{Text} & Very long text \\ \cline{2-4}

     Text& \multicolumn{2}{C|}{Text} & Very long text \\ \hline

    & \multirow{2}{*}{text} & text & text \\ \cline{3-4}

    & & text & very long text \\ \cline{2-4}

    Text & \multirow{1}{*}{Text} & Text & text \\ \cline{3-4}

    & \multirow{1}{*}{Text} & text & Very long text \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

THX in advance!

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419647/how-do-i-use-multirow-in-latex, actually your question is duplicate to it.

Comment: Also related: [newline in multirow environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331716/134144) and [How can I make lines break automatically in multirow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157373/134144)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please post the code you used to produce those tables as a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Helping and debugging code is in general easier when we see code.

Comment: updated the question. What you guys linked didn't quite help me get it all done as wanted. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

your question is very similar to questions in links provided in comments below your question. with small effort you should on given examples design your code. anyway, here we go:

- your table has for columns but you define five
- `\multirow{1}{*}{...}` hasn't sense. of one row cell its use is superflous. only make clutter in your code
- for multi line text in `\multirow` cells you should define width of this cells. this you can done locally, for example as `\multirow{4}{2cm}{....}` or define width of column (as is done in mwe below) and than use `\multieow{4}{=}{...}` which take over defined width of column
- use `\multicolumn{2}{C|}{Text}` means that text in this column can have width of one column. for wide width of one line text in cells is better to use `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Text}`. however, in cases, that you like to have multi line text in this cells, you need increase its width. for this i use

```
\newlength\colwidth % new length
\setlength\colwidth{\dimexpr\hsize/4+2\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}% calculation width 
                                                                       % of one column as
                                                                       % calculated by tabularx
\newcommand\mcxx[1]{\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\colwidth}C|}{#1}}%
```

complete mwe is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newlength\colwidth
\setlength\colwidth{\dimexpr\hsize/4+2\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\newcommand\mcxx[1]{\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\colwidth}C|}{#1}}%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}C|
                        *{3}{ >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}C|}
                            }
    \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{Text}   & \mcxx{Text}   & Very long text    \\ \cline{2-4}
                        & \mcxx{Text}   & Very long text    \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{Text}   & \mcxx{Text}   & Very long text    \\ \cline{2-4}
                        & \mcxx{Text}   & Very long text    \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{=}{Test text}
                        & \multirow{2}{=}{text}
                            & Text      & Text              \\ \cline{3-4}
                        &   & Text      & very long text    \\ \cline{2-4}
                        & \multirow{2}{=}{Text\\ text}
                            & Text      & Text              \\ \cline{3-4}
                        &   & text      & Very long text    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

is this what you looking for?

Comment: I appreciate your example but I don't understand the meaning of `>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}` and `>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}`? What is `\hsize` here?

Comment: @Tarass, as i seid in answer: column width. `\hsize=0.5\hsize` means, that this column has width equal to  0.5 width calculated by `tabularx`. by this you can change width of `X` columns.  for details see documentation for `tabularx` https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx?lang=en

Comment: I wonder because `the sum of width must stay inchanged` : in the doc example `{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X}` the sum is 2 for 2 columns, but in your example the sum is 5 for 4 columns ...

Comment: How does one know about 'textwidth/5' with 4 declared columns?

Comment: For this question I used this table preambule to fine tune the columnn width with one parameter : `\newlength{\TbW}
\setlength{\TbW}{.16\linewidth}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
 |X*{2}{|m{\TbW}}|m{2\TbW}|}\hline`

Comment: a just asked the question. Thank you, it is very interesting.

Comment: @Zarko I think you are crucially relying on this part of the TX documentation: `As with most rules, these may be broken if you know what you are doing.`

Comment: although the mismatch 4!=5 accounts for why your spanning headings are not centred

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, corrected. but still have some problems with my solution, which now avoided to restrict me to cases when `\multicolumn` contain one line contain and therefore can be simple `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}` (this is also considered in `multirow` cells. thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: If I take your code and try to compile it I get: "!File ended while scanning for use of \@argdef. Suspect you have forgotten a '}'" Error.

I also don't quite understand the parameters you give tabularx. Using Texmaker 4.3

Comment: @jaaq, i try to correct code directly here, but it seems with this i introduce new errors. now i copy complete tested code from my editor which should work.

Comment: @Zarko I am terribly sorry to bother you further but in which environment are you compiling this? I am running Texmaker4 on windows 10 and it throws out lots of "missing number, treated as a zero" errors. Also how does it look on your pc?

Comment: @jaaq, i use 64-bit miktex (recent version) and for editor winedt 10.2. i tested my code again. it works without any warnings and errors. by it i generated shod table image.